# scrollIntoView() shifting the complete page

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

Environment: Firefox 16/27 and Chrome 33

I have a `<div>`(with scroll bar) containing lots of elements `<p>`.

If I call `scrollIntoView()` on a `<p>` element, I expect only the scroll of the `div` to move, but the complete page (outside of the `<div>`) gets scrolled.

Example on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7fH8K/7/

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just call `scrollIntoView()` with the parameter `false` to indicate that it should not be scrolled to the top.

See the [description for `Element.scrollIntoView()` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView) for more info.

The reason why the JSFiddle page is scrolled down is that `scrollIntoView()` scrolls all scrollable ancestor elements to display the element you called `scrollIntoView()` on. And because the `<body>` of the page is actually higher than the viewport but only scrolling is hidden via `overflow: hidden;`, it scrolls the page down trying to align the `p` element with the top.

Here's a simple example of this behavior:

File *scroll.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Main page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 120%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        header {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        iframe {
            height: 100px;
            width: 300px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header></header>
        <iframe src="scroll2.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

File *scroll2.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Scrolling &lt;iframe&gt;</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function scrollLastParagraphIntoView() {
            var lastParagraph = document.getElementById("p10");
            lastParagraph.scrollIntoView();
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="scrollLastParagraphIntoView()">Scroll last paragraph into view</button>
        <p>Paragraph 1</p>
        <p>Paragraph 2</p>
        <p>Paragraph 3</p>
        <p>Paragraph 4</p>
        <p>Paragraph 5</p>
        <p>Paragraph 6</p>
        <p>Paragraph 7</p>
        <p>Paragraph 8</p>
        <p>Paragraph 9</p>
        <p id="p10">Paragraph 10</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When you click the *Scroll last paragraph into view* button, the whole page will be scrolled so that the paragraph is displayed at the top of the viewport.

Comment: That fixed the problem.. but still can't figure out why it was scrolling the complete page....also cant accept your answer as it does not explain what went wrong.

Comment: I hope my example makes it clearer why the whole page is scrolled and not just the `<div>` that contains the `<p>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
scrollIntoView({ block: 'end' })
```

or for smooth scroll:

```
scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' })
```

Comment: Note that at the time of this comment, Safari (sadly) does not support these options. It only accepts the boolean parameter: https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview

Answer (score 1):

onClick we can use the below logic

```
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;
```

and for smooth scroll behaviour we can use

CSS Properties :

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
overscroll-behavior: contain;
```

this can avoid page scroll or page shift which happens with

`scrollIntoView({ block: 'start', behavior: 'smooth' })`

Comment: Thank you for the CSS properties! They made the trick to mimic scrollIntoView smooth behavior. Just one thing to add to your response: `target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;` requires the parent element to have a relative position. If it doesn't have it, you will need to substract its offset `target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop - target.parentNode.offsetTop;`